# How Do I Run Prettier Only on Files That I Want to Commit?

Tags: javascript, git, code-formatting, pre-commit-hook, prettier

Using [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky), I've set up my `package.json` with a precommit hook so that my JavaScript code is formatted using [Prettier](https://prettier.io) before every commit:

```
{
  "name": "prettier-demo",
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "prettier --write **/*.js && git add ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "prettier": "^1.8.2"
  }
}
```

This works fine, but there are two drawbacks:

1. If I have a large project with thousands of JavaScript files, I have to wait for Prettier to process all of them, even if only a few have changed; this can take very long and gets on my nerves quickly when it is done with every commit
2. Sometimes I want to stage just a couple of files for committing, leaving other changes out of the commit; because I do a `git add .` after running Prettier, all my changes will always end up in the commit

**How can I run Prettier before every commit *only on the files that have been staged*, ignoring unstaged or unchanged files?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do that using [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged):

> Linting makes more sense when running before committing your code. By doing that you can ensure no errors are going into repository and enforce code style. But running a lint process on a whole project is slow and linting results can be irrelevant. Ultimately you only want to lint files that will be committed.
>
> This project contains a script that will run arbitrary npm and shell tasks with a list of staged files as an argument, filtered by a specified glob pattern.

Install *lint-staged* and *husky*, which is required for pre-commit hooks, with this command:

```
npm install --save-dev lint-staged husky
```

Change your package.json as follows:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: @PatrickHund I agree, but I also like your hands-on attitude :) You can still undelete your answer if you want.

Comment: No, that's fine. Another dev on my team had actually set the precommit up with lint-staged, but it didn't work properly, because he put "git add ." in the config instead of "git add". So I wrote that bash script, could have just removed the dot and be done with it 

Comment: I did this with prettier-eslint, same exact syntax as answer. 
```"lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,less,json}": [
      "prettier-eslint --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I have also seen a 'precise-commits' repo, stating it only prettifies the parts of file staged i.e. staged hunks and not the entire file. What do you think about this? I haven't tried it yet. https://github.com/nrwl/precise-commits

Comment: @AmirEldor I think that is a bad idea as this could lead to inconsistent formatting within a single file.

Comment: @str, true, however, it might prevent accidental merge conflicts if two people prettify the same file as a whole in two branches (unless git is smart about similar lines from two branches). Also, git annotate info would be preserved rather than having the same person annotated on the whole file after they prettify it.

Comment: @AmirEldor Git is smart enough to handle that without merge conflicts. I would rather have messy annotations than messy code. But that is up to you ;)

Comment: Is there a way to run linters only against newly created (added) files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540244/linting-only-newly-added-files

Answer (score 23):

I found that just running:

```sh
prettier --write $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter d | grep '\.js$' | xargs)
```

was quite enough for my needs, just made an alias and used that.

Comment: that actually returned some results that had .js in the path.
this worked better for me: git diff --name-only | grep '\.ts$'

Comment: also I just learned that this will fail when a file is removed.
Prettier will try to format the removed file.
To make it work use 
`prettier --write $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter d | grep '\.ts$'  | xargs)`

Comment: Thanks @NitsanBaleli I updated the message to include your grep match fix and filter deleted fixes !

Comment: If you're working on a TypeScript project, this will match .js, .ts, .jsx and .tsx: `prettier --write $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter d | grep -e '\.[tj]sx\?$' | xargs)`

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a way to make ```prettier --write``` pass if there is no file/dir/glob arguments supplied to it?  In this situation this is caused by there being no output from the git diff command

Comment: Note that this will only take unstaged files, you can switch with this command unstaged:`git diff`, staged:`git diff --staged`, both:`git diff HEAD`

Answer (score 7):

I used this package [pretty-quick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-quick)

added a script in my `package.json`

```
"pretty-quick": "pretty-quick"
```

under `scripts {}`

Then in my `pre-commit` hook under `.husky/pre-commit`,

I added

```
`npm run pretty-quick`
```

Comment: Sadly, `pretty-quick` doesn't receiving any updates for several years and dosen't work with prettier >= 3.x.x

Comment: `pretty-quick` now works again for Prettier v3.  https://github.com/prettier/pretty-quick/issues/164#issuecomment-1895400862

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to add the devDependency `lint-staged` you can also do the same with a Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# chmod +x this and save in your PATH. Assumes `prettier` is in your `devDependencies` already
BASE=$(git merge-base master HEAD) # change master to whatever your trunk branch is
FILES=$(git diff --name-only $BASE HEAD | xargs)

npx prettier --list-different $FILES

# Want eslint too?
# npx eslint --ignore-path=.prettierignore $FILES
```

Answer (score 3):

The prettier docs has a [section](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html) on this.

I use pretty-quick

```
npx husky-init
npm install --save-dev pretty-quick
npx husky set .husky/pre-commit "npx pretty-quick --staged"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can construct such command in three steps:

1. #### Take all changed files using `git diff`

   - `git diff --name-only --diff-filter d` *<- only **un**staged files*
   - `git diff --name-only --diff-filter d --staged` *<- only staged files*
   - `git diff --name-only --diff-filter d HEAD` *<- both*

   note:

   - `--name-only` only file paths, without diffs (absolute to project root)
   - `--relative` switch paths to be relative to current directory instead
   - `--diff-filter=d` excludes deleted files, otherwise prettier fails
2. #### Filter out files by extension

   *note: under windows it is not possible to use "or" in `grep -E '(json|css)'`, but it is possible to get the same behavior with additional `-e PATTERN` commands.*

   - `grep -e '\.[jt]sx\?$' -e '\.css$' -e '\.json$'` to match `js|jsx|ts|tsx`, `css` and `json`
   - `grep -e 'src.*\.[jt]sx\?$'` use `src.*` to specify directory
3. #### Put that all together

   - `-u` With `--ignore-unknown` (or `-u`), prettier will ignore unknown files matched by patterns.
   - `npx prettier` will execute prettier from local `node_modules`. To run global prettier, use just `prettier <command>`

```
npx prettier -u --write $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD | grep '\.js$' | xargs)
```

#### For **Windows** users using UnxUtils or Git for Windows:

- `npx.cmd prettier` will execute prettier from local `node_modules`. To run global prettier, use just `prettier <command>`

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD | grep -e '\.js$' | xargs npx.cmd prettier -u --write
```

When used as a script in `package.json`, you can omit `npx`

```
"scripts": {
  "format:changed": "git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD | grep -e 'src.*\\.[jt]sx\\?$' -e 'src.*\\.json$' -e 'src.*\\.css$' -e 'src.*\\.md$' | xargs prettier -u --write"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this out this only checks the modified files and performs eslint, prettier and adds it to git.**

Below code works for me:

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const { ESLint } = require("eslint");

module.exports = {
  "./src/**/*.{ts,js,json}": async (fileNames) => {
    const escapedFileNames = fileNames.map((fileName) => resolve(fileName)).join(" ");
    const filesToLint = await removeIgnoredFiles(fileNames);

    return [
      `eslint --max-warnings=0 --fix ${filesToLint}`,
      `prettier --relative --write ${escapedFileNames}`,
      `git add ${escapedFileNames}`,
    ];
  },
};

async function removeIgnoredFiles(files) {
  const eslint = new ESLint();
  const isIgnored = await Promise.all(files.map((file) => eslint.isPathIgnored(file)));
  return files.filter((_, i) => !isIgnored[i]).join(" ");
}
```