# Is it possible to format only modified lines in pre-commit hooks

Tags: git, commit, prettier, pre-commit-hook

Using Prettier when we commit changes it formats all the code inside the file in Husky **pre-commit**. Is there any better method to change only modified lines of code in the file?.

Comment: Do you use `lint-staged`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610566/7976758 ? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pre-commit-hook+prettier

Comment: @phd I believe they want a solution specific to lines rather than files.

Comment: @Zweih 9 months later there still no answer so I doubt there is a way.

Comment: I think I've found a solution, will answer the question if testing keeps going well.

Comment: @Zweih thank you, waiting for your answer.

Comment: I think the guy gave up... did anybody bothered on submitting a feature-request for this on the Prettier's Github repo? We could of course write an script to revert the formatting made to lines not originally changed, but a config option from Prettier itself will be great...